# Widgets with groups / sub widgets? Widget in a widget?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I tried to find anything about adding a widget within a widget area. That widget should be a widget group / sub widget area.

**I've found a plugin that does this:**

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extensible-widgets/
- http://jidd.jimisaacs.com/files/2010/02/wpew-screen-9.png

**What I really want is to dynamically create something like this without the help from plugins:**

- http://www.gabfirethemes.com/demos/newspro/

Any bright ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with the last link? Any explanation? Do you have a link for the plugin behind the screenshot? Furthermore plugins are exactly the same as dropping it into the functions.php file. The only difference is their location. Adding plugins is nothing bad.

Comment: The last link is what I want to create with widget in a widget. If you look at the link it's widgets everywhere. Some widgets are inside others. The link for the screenshot is the link above it (Extensible widgets). I know plugins is not bad but lazy users want to activate the theme without having to activate themes for it to work.

Comment: Ad last link) From where do you know that these are widgets? Could also be plugins or code from inside the functions.php file. The easiest way then is to download the plugin, place it inside your theme and - instead of activating it via admin UI - `include` the main plugin file. Then you don't have to activate it and still avoid writing your own.

Comment: I did not get it what you are asking for please elaborate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look at [**Tabber Tabs Widget**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tabber-tabs-widget/screenshots/) plugin does it you will see that it creates a widget and a new "sidebar", now if you place widgets in that sidebar they will show only where you place the plugins widget.

and if you look at what [**Tabbed Widgets**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tabbed-widgets/screenshots/) plugin does, it creates a widgets that pulls a list of all registered widgets in to a dropdown and lets you choose which ones you want.

both seem like nice ways to achieve that , depends on what you need.